# After logout the user should not be able to re enter into the site by typing the url of the internal pages in the address bar

Tags: c#, asp.net

i m relatively new to C# and ASP.NET and I am having trouble designing an authentication system.

I have created a website where the user has to login, after which he can access various pages in this site.  When the user clicks a logout link, he returns to the login page and is given the message "you have successfully logout."  Now how do I prevent the user from typing the URL of one of the internal pages, bypassing my authentication?  While working with PHP, I used `session_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` at the beginning and the end of each page to control authentication.  What is a similar model in ASP.NET?

Also how do I include a `.cs` file from app_code folder to a `aspx.cs`?

Comment: I would suggest you only ask one question at a time.  If you have two questions, then ask two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now how do i prevent re entry into the site by typing the url of the internal pages in the address bar.

How are you actually tracking the authentication?  [Forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)?  [Windows authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)?  Something custom?  Essentially, what you need to do is have those pages check for a valid authentication token.  If no such token exists, redirect to the login page or an error or something to that effect.

You can do this by checking for authentication manually in the `Page_Init` method (which can access Session data, Cookies data, etc. where you'd store such a token), you can [use various methods built-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfs7yc7.aspx), etc.

The concept is the same as it was in PHP, the tooling is just a little different.

> While working with PHP i used session_start() and ob_end_flush() at the beginning and the end of each page.....What is it im supposed to use in c#?

You don't need to explicitly start/end session state in ASP.NET.  Any code in the scope of the web application can access session state/values via [`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx).  Any request coming from the same session will have this data associated with it.

> Also how do i include .cs file from app_code folder to a aspx.cs

While in PHP you had to include files, in ASP.NET it's compiled code so the file isn't so important.  What you need to reference is the namespace/class to use the code.  For example...

If you have the following in a file in `App_Code`:

```
namespace MyApplicationCode
{
    public class SomeCode
    {
        // stuff in the class
    }
}
```

Then from any code within the application you should be able to use it by it's fully-qualified name (`MyApplicationCode.SomeCode`):

```
var someVariable = new MyApplicationCode.SomeCode();
```

Additionally, you can add a `using` statement in the header of the code file:

```
using MyApplicationCode;
```

And then access it directly:

```
var someVariable = new SomeCode();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using FormsAuthentication, this is simple to do using configuration in web.config.

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="default.aspx" protection="All" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60" />
  </authentication>
```

This configuration forces aspx to ensure that all pages in the site can only be accessed by authorized users.

However, there is a logic problem with this configuration: no one would ever be able to login since they must be authorized to access any page in the site.

You can fix this, however, by opening "holes" in this protected by adding specific pages and indicating they can be authorized by anyone:

```
  <location path="default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user is successfully authenticated with his credentials, a cookie is set with a session id that corresponds to a file that stores value on the server. This cookie confirms to the server that the user is authenticated.

Check how your system handles sessions, it can be done without a session cookie, too:

(pseudo-code)

```
if (User.Login(formUsername, formPassword)) {
    SetCookie ("LoggedIn", 1, Time() + 3600);
}
```

Now, whicever page needs a logged in user to be viewed, you just check if the user has the cookie set:

(pseudo-code)

```
if (CookieIsSet("LoggedIn")) {
    // this page can be viewed
}
else {
    Redirect ("/notAuthorized");
}
```

When you log the user out, you can delete the cookie by setting the expiration date in the past:

(pseudo-code)

```
SetCookie ("LoggedIn", 1, Time() - 3600);
```

Now, the user cannot view the internal page as the check (CookieIsSet(...)) will fail. Now, functions, methods and all the details depend on the system, but it always works like this:

1. if credentials are ok, set a cookie
2. whenever an internal page is visited, check if cookie is set
3. when logging out, delete the cookie

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the user typed in the address bar I would simply check the UrlReferer in page load of protected pages, other aspects should be controlled by web security and state management

```
 if (Request.UrlReferrer == null)
        Response.Redirect("errorpage.aspx");
```

Comment: not bad idea, but some times browsers or plugins try to stop the trace and set UrlReferrer to null, even if it is not.